# Jquery get method won't render xhtml pages

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf

I am trying to render a jsf page with extension .xhtml when user chooses a jquery tab, the pages are called using jquery ajax, The problem is when I place a html page in the get method it works , but when the pages are .xhtml it is not rendered , here is an example

`$.get("/example/page.xhtml")", function(data) { $(".loads_here").append(data); ...}`

Comment: It seems you are closing the $.get request too soon notice the )" after the url there...

Comment: There are other code what really matters is that it can't read the .xhtml , other than that it works fine

Comment: IMO the URL `/example/page.xhtml` cannot be found. Use `${request.contextPath}/example/page.xhtml`.

Comment: It didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all I found the solution, the error was with the page itself, xhtml pages are organized, and the html pages I was changing to xhtml were containing some undefined attributes that the page could load so it gave me a 404 error , but when I removed them it rendered easily.